# why is the unsigned binary range of 2^6 63 bits?

Tags: binary, bit

unsigned 6 bits ranges from 0 to 63, and you can get there because 2^6 = 64. but wouldn't six bit binary string only go up to 2^5? the first bit is for 2^0 no ...? where am i going wrong here? i'm aware this is a very simple question please help me understand as i do not know very much

Answer (score 2):

A six bit binary string goes up from `0b000000` to

```
  0b111111
= 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
=  32 +  16 +   8 +   4 +   2 +   1
=  63
=  64 - 1
= 2^6 - 1
```

That the sum of `2^i` for `i in 0, 1, … (n-1)` evaluates to `2^n - 1` is a peculiarity of the number two.